# POSIX "sort -n" alpha characters between zero and 1?

Tags: bash, shell, sorting

I'm having trouble getting POSIX "sort" to behave the way I want it to.  When sorting numeric file names, those that start with letters show up between 0 and 1.

Why does this happen?

Is there a different sort option I can use to achieve the desired result?

```
$touch 0 1 a
$ls | sort -n
```

Desired Output:
    0
    1
    a

Actual Output:
    0
    a
    1

In the gnu implementation, "-g" does roughly what I want, but that's not POSIX.  Which unfortunately, means I can't use it.

Comment: maybe it is a bad idea, you can first add a large number to those lines that not starting with number. after sorting, removing the big number.

Comment: Why do you want to sort filenames in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want explicitly sort output as

- first numerically sorted files so 0, 1, 2, 11, 222, and after
- all other files sorted

you can do it for example with

```
cat <(ls -1 | grep '^[0-9]' |sort -n) <(ls -1 | grep -v '^[0-9]' | sort)
```

so catenate output of two commands

- sort numerically files what begins with numbers, and
- sort other files (what aren't begins with numbers)

but, this is works with `bash` only and don't know how much bash is POSIX, if `bash` is not ok you can use temporary files...

Comment: I ended up using a combination of sort & grep [0-9] to get the results I was after.  So I suppose this is a correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Its because you have the `-n`. That means numeric so `a` is being treated as `0`. Get rid of the `-n` and you should be right (at the cost of `11` now coming before `2`)

Comment: I'm doing the '-n' because I want a numeric sort.  But if that means 'a' is treated as 0, I guess that makes sense??

Comment: But actually, you don't necessarily want a numeric sort if you want an output of '0 1 a'